# Bash sort order of find - files before directory with same name

Tags: bash, sorting

## Situation

Let's assume we have a directory like the following:

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1_1.md
│   └── 1_2.md
├── 1.md
├── 2
│   ├── 2_1.md
│   └── 2_2.md
└── 2.md
```

This can be recreated by:

```
mkdir example
cd example
echo "# Chapter 1" >> 1.md
mkdir 1
cd 1
echo "## Section 1.1" >> 1_1.md
echo "## Section 1.2" >> 1_2.md
cd ..
echo "# Chapter 2" >> 2.md
mkdir 2
cd 2
echo "## Section 2.1" >> 2_1.md
echo "## Section 2.2" >> 2_2.md
```

Now I would like to concatenate all `.md` files into one `.md` file in this order:

```
- 1.md 
- 1_1.md
- 1_2.md
- 2.md
- 2_1.md
- 2_2.md
```

## Tries

Unfortunately,

```
$ cat `find -type f | sort`
```

gives me

```
## Section 1.1
## Section 1.2
# Chapter 1
## Section 2.1
## Section 2.2
# Chapter 2
```

where the ordering of chapters vs. sections is mixed up as

```
$ find -type f | sort
```

gives me

```
./1/1_1.md
./1/1_2.md
./1.md
./2/2_1.md
./2/2_2.md
./2.md
```

## Question

How can I force the chapters above the respective sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `sort` command supports the `-V` option ...

```
-V, --version-sort
       natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

... we can use this to sort the file names as wanted:

```
$ find -type f | sort -V
./1.md
./1/1_1.md
./1/1_2.md
./2.md
./2/2_1.md
./2/2_2.md
```

Now pipe the results to `xargs/cat` to display the strings in the desired order:

```
$ find -type f | sort -V | xargs -r cat
# Chapter 1
## Section 1.1
## Section 1.2
# Chapter 2
## Section 2.1
## Section 2.2
```

Comment: Thanks. Although the other answers work as well, this seems to be the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it as follows:

```
cd example
cat $(ls -1v *.md */*.md)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of how you example filenames are structured, you could do this:

```
find -type f -printf "%f\t%p\n" | 
sort -t_ -n -k1 -k2 |
cut -f2- |
xargs cat
```

First print the filenames with paths separated by tabs. Then number sort with `_` as separator on first then on second field (ie. chapter and section). Then remove the filename, leaving the paths.